# How to configure Spring JavaMailSenderImpl for hotmail

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc

this is my XML configuration file in a maven project, I am trying to send an auto-generated message using a Hotmail id, sometimes it's working fine and sometimes I am getting an error sending mail

```xml
<bean id=" email" class=" org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage"></bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl" id="mailSender">
    <property value="smtp.live.com" name="host"/>
    <property value="587" name="port"/>
    <property value="xxxxxx@hotmail.com" name="username"/>
    <property value="xxxxxxxxx" name="password"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">465</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

after changing port name 587 to 25 it's working fine